# Mongo Aggregation Framework with Mongoose raising Document Limit exception on simple Projection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection **links** (schema below) with almost 500k entries.

```
 {
   url,
   title,
   owner,
   stars: { users: [{ name }]},
   createdAt
 }
```

and I really do not understand why the simple aggregation projection

```
var projection = { $project: { _id: 1, url: 1, title: 1, createdAt: 1 } }
Link.aggregate([projection]).exec(resultCallback);
```

raises an

```
MongoError: exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)
```

could you explain me ?

I'm using Mongoose (3.8.8) and Mongodb (2.6.0)

Comment: Your code here does not make any sense. You declare `projection` and then you use `project`. What does that second variable contain? Also how big is your collection? You are asking for the whole thing back as a single BSON document in an array. Certainly over 16MB. Do you need to know how to use a cursor or output to a collection?

Comment: hi @NeilLunn. thanks for the heads up. It was a typo.

Comment: I also have more to say there for you to consider. Read again.

Comment: Yeah, I understand with few words what the aggregation is doing. Thanks. Cursor will be my option !

Comment: @NeilLunn in fact, what am i trying to do, is sort the relevant links using a custom sort. To do that, I am projecting, sorting and limiting. But the query is getting too slow (http://pastie.org/9270573). I have almost 500k links. have any tip how to design that ?

Comment: You can ask another question that shows your document structure and preferably some attempt at aggregation to do this task. But your present question as to resolving your error should be covered by the answer already given. So it is polite to accept the good advice given. Also who knows, your new question might be considered worthy of up-votes. If you consider, this current question may not have been asked before as to how to get a cursor, so possibly some reward for you here as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for your time. I already created another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106379/mongo-custom-sort-strategy

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the options available from MongoDB 2.6 and on-wards are fully available in the `.aggregate()` method implementation in mongoose. But there should be an options "hash/object" available after the pipeline argument. So basically:

```
var pipeline = [{ $project: { _id: 1, url: 1, title: 1, createdAt: 1 } }];
Link.aggregate(pipeline,{ cursor: true}, function(err,cursor) {

});
```

Or if mongoose doesn't like that for some reason then just get the raw node driver collection:

```
var pipeline = [{ $project: { _id: 1, url: 1, title: 1, createdAt: 1 } }];
Link.collection.aggregate(pipeline,{ cursor: true}, function(err,cursor) {

   if (err)
      throw err;

   // Do something with the cursor which is actually more akin to a node
   // stream interface with a basic .next() method and other helpers.

});
```

Otherwise since you output is blowing up the 16MB BSON limit then you can always output to a collection:

```
var pipeline = [
    { $project: { _id: 1, url: 1, title: 1, createdAt: 1 } },
    { $out: "newcollection" }
];
```

But since you are probably just really testing, why not just use the **`$limit`** pipeline stage until you work out the rest of your aggregation:

```
var pipeline = [
    { $project: { _id: 1, url: 1, title: 1, createdAt: 1 } },
    { $limit: 50 }
];
```

So there are a few different ways to handle things.

Comment: It's available in the API form *if* you include the `cursor` method. At least that's the case in Mongoose 3.9.x.